# How encrypt data with a public key in node-forge with 3DES algorithm?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, node-forge

node-forge offers only a generic encrypt function with RSAES encryption system:

```
var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(pem);
// encrypt data with a public key using RSAES PKCS#1 v1.5
var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(bytes, 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5');
```

I would like to use 3DES instead of RSAES.

Is there any misconception in the world of cryptography in my question?

Comment: Yes, RSA is a public-key cryptosystem where as 3DES is a private key cryptosystem.

Comment: Do you mean asymmetrical and symmetrical?